# Normed space without inner product

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

I'm looking for an example of a normed space in which the norm doesn't create an inner product. I know that the condition for that is that the Parallelogram Law doesn't apply.

I tried using some $L^p$ spaces, but I soon discovered that there is in fact an inner product. The other examples that came to my mind were in $\Bbb R^n$, but there I'm sure that the norm always induces an inner product.

Comment: Where did you discover that $L^p$ has an inner product? Famously, only $L^2$ does.

Comment: Well, I was just trying some functions and they all satisfied the parallelogram law, so I thought it was not a coincidence, because I have tried 4 or 5. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: For $L^p$ spaces $(x,y)$ has $x\in L^p$ and $y\in L^q$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$  so you don't have anorm unless $p=q=2$.

Comment: It‘s probably better if you give us your inner products and we tell you what went wrong with them. As I‘ve mentioned, all $L^p$ spaces for $p \neq 2$ are not inner product spaces.

Comment: I used , on $\Bbb R^n$, the inner product defined by $\langle x,y \rangle = 1/4(||x+y||-||x-y||)$.

Comment: How does that have to do with $L^p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C[0,1]$ is a good example. Consider $f$ and $g$ with the following properties: $0\leq f,g \leq 1$, $f(x)=0$ for  $x \leq \frac  12 -\frac  1 n$, $f(x) =1$ for  $x \geq \frac 1 2$, $g(x)=1$ for  $x \leq \frac  12 -\frac  1 n$, $g(x) =0$ for  $x \geq \frac 1 2+\frac  1 n$. Show that $\|f+g\|^{2} +\|f-g\|^{2} <2\|f\|^{2}+2\|g\|^{2}$.